# IceFaces Push Renderer does not work - FacesContext is null for the current thread

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I am trying to build a sample application using ICEfaces 2.0 , glassfish 3.0.1, JMS.
 I have created a JMS Topic publisher which is a desktop application and publishes some data to the TOPIC, on the other end I have a web application where a user subscribes to this TOPIC to receive messages from the it. In order to apply the page updates asynchronously I am using ICEFaces PushRenderer. PushRenderer works in the scenario where PushRenderer.render() is being called by the managed Bean instance, but fails when being called from the onMessage() function which is a listener for the JMS messages.The push rendering fails, saying "The current thread does not have FacesContext associated with it. Now in order to make this work, is how can I execute the call to PushRenderer.render from the managed bean instance thread OR is there another way to make the PushRenderer.render work when onMessage() is being called by the TOPIC publisher.?
Please help regarding this. I am looking for other ways to make this work. Also the same procedure works with ICEFaces 1.8.2 SessionRenderer.render but it fails with PushRenderer.render as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the ondemand renderer, something like:

```
renderManager.getOnDemandRenderer(identifier).requestRender();
```